# insert content to the first selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a checkbox which I want to insert before a cloned phrase and list.

```
$("p:contains('text'), ul:last",e).clone().prepend(myCheckbox);
```

My checkbox is now inserted before each phrase and each list.
I just want to insert the checkbox before the phrase.
Is that possible?

Thank you.

Edit:
HTMl-Structure to clone:

```
<p>Text</p>
<ul>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
</ul>
```

This is what it shoudl look like:
`<input type='checkbox'>
<p>Text</p>
<ul>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
</ul>`

But it looks like:
`<input type='checkbox'>
<p>Text</p>
<input type='checkbox'>
<ul>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
  <li>Listpoint</li>
</ul>`

Comment: Yes, I guess... Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to trim the results:

```
$("p:contains('text'), ul:last", e).clone().filter('p').prepend(myCheckbox);
```

Comment: When I use filter the list isn't displayed anymore. I edited my post above.

Comment: Well, I just had to create a variable and filter the p out ;-) Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Use `before()`:

```
$('p:contains("text"), ul:last', e).clone().before(myCheckbox);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Ye5bS/